Find a gap > 10min and select begin/end dates in timestamp logs
Lets say I have a table with logs. Two columns: one with user name and second with record timestamp.
Records appear in table every 10 minutes for each user IF this user was active.



user
timestamp




user1
07/08/2024 20:10:00,000000


user2
07/08/2024 20:10:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 20:10:00,000000


user1
07/08/2024 20:20:00,000000


user2
07/08/2024 20:20:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 20:20:00,000000


user1
07/08/2024 20:30:00,000000


user2
07/08/2024 20:30:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 20:30:00,000000


user2
07/08/2024 20:40:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 20:40:00,000000


user1
07/08/2024 20:50:00,000000


user2
07/08/2024 20:50:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 20:50:00,000000


user1
07/08/2024 21:00:00,000000


user1
07/08/2024 21:10:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 22:00:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 22:20:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 22:30:00,000000



From such table I need to display data:

user
begin (begin of the log sequence)
end (end of the log sequence )

"Sequence" means that records for the selected user appear every 10 minutes, so every gap > 10min ends current the sequence and the next row for the user starts the next sequence. If there is only one record then I need to display this record as begin and add 10 minutes to begin timestamp to set end.
So the result there should be like this:



user
begin
end




user1
07/08/2024 20:10:00,000000
07/08/2024 20:30:00,000000


user2
07/08/2024 20:10:00,000000
07/08/2024 20:50:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 20:10:00,000000
07/08/2024 20:50:00,000000


user1
07/08/2024 20:50:00,000000
07/08/2024 21:10:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 22:00:00,000000
07/08/2024 22:10:00,000000


user3
07/08/2024 22:20:00,000000
07/08/2024 22:30:00,000000



How can I do this?

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT username,
       begin_time,
       CASE
       WHEN begin_time = end_time
       THEN end_time + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
       ELSE end_time
       END AS end_time
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY username
         ORDER BY datetime
         MEASURES
           FIRST(datetime) AS begin_time,
           LAST(datetime) AS end_time
         PATTERN ( first_time consecutive_times* )
         DEFINE
           consecutive_times AS datetime <= PREV(datetime) + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (username, datetime) AS
SELECT 'user1', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:10:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:10:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:10:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:20:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:20:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:20:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:30:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:30:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:30:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:40:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:40:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:50:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:50:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 20:50:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 21:00:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 21:10:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 22:00:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 22:20:00.000000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', TIMESTAMP '2024-08-07 22:30:00.000000' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



USERNAME
BEGIN_TIME
END_TIME




user1
2024-08-07 20:10:00.000000000
2024-08-07 20:30:00.000000000


user1
2024-08-07 20:50:00.000000000
2024-08-07 21:10:00.000000000


user2
2024-08-07 20:10:00.000000000
2024-08-07 20:50:00.000000000


user3
2024-08-07 20:10:00.000000000
2024-08-07 20:50:00.000000000


user3
2024-08-07 22:00:00.000000000
2024-08-07 22:10:00.000000000


user3
2024-08-07 22:20:00.000000000
2024-08-07 22:30:00.000000000



fiddle

It works perfectly! thank you so much!

Another way to solve this is to use the LAG() and SUM() window functions. The first CTE flags records with a time difference of 0 if it is within a 10-minute range and 1 otherwise. The second CTE creates a running total and assigns a group number to succeeding records.
WITH records AS (
    SELECT t.*,
             CASE WHEN datetime = LAG(datetime, 1, datetime) 
                  OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY datetime) + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
    FROM mytable t
),
groups AS (
  SELECT r.*, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY datetime) AS grp
  FROM records r
)
SELECT username, MIN(datetime) AS BEGIN_TIME, MAX(datetime) AS END_TIME
FROM groups
GROUP BY username, grp;

